# select top products in orders table

Tags: c#, sql

I have two tables:

```
product(id, reference, name)  
order(id, productId, date, quantity)
```

Every order has one or many products. The order table can have many lines of the same product. I need to select the 5 best seller products for today in the order table. I try this join to select the products of every order on today.

```cs
from order in orders where order.date == DateTime.Today
join product in products on product.Id equals order.productId
select new {product.name, product.quantity, product.Id};
```

Now I have a list of products sold on today, which can have multiple lines of the same products.
So I tried this to add the quantity of the repeated product:

```cs
for (int i = 1; i <= productList.ToArray().Count(); i++)
{
    foreach (var product in productList)
    {
        if (productList.Contains(product))
            quantite += product.Quantite;
        else
            quantite = product.Quantite;
```

I didn't find a solution how to get the top 5 articles!

Comment: The statement `if (productList.Contains(product))` will always be true because `product` come from a foreach loop over `productList`

Comment: yes, you're right but I didn't found a solution

Comment: The for-statement is obsolete since the foreach does it already. Also `productList.ToArray().Count()` counts the elements in the array, but the array has a `Length` property. But converting an IEnumerable to an array just to get the count is not necessary. `productList..Count()` alone would produce the same result; however, `foreach` makes this count unnecessary. `from order in orders on order.date equals DateTime.Toda` should be `from order in orders where order.date == DateTime.Today`. All in all, your code does not make much sense.

Comment: With these tables, an order can have only one product (in any quantity) and not many products as you stated.

Answer (score 3):

Try following :

```
var results = (from order in orders on order.date equals DateTime.Today
   join product in products on product.Id equals order.productId
   select new {name = product.name, quantity = order.quantity, id = product.Id})
   .GroupBy(x => x.id)
   .Select(x => new { name = x.First().name, id = x.Key, totalQuantity = x.Sum(y => y.quantity)}
   .OrderByDescending(x => x.totalQuantity)
   .Take(5)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: would you explain how he understand that he should add the quantity of only the same repeated product please?

Comment: The GroupBy create a two dimensional array <key, List<object>> All the products with the same key (id) will be put into a list and the SUM method will get the total quantity.  the Select will enumerate through each of the keys (ids).

Comment: the object type in <key,list<object>> is orders but I need the product to display the name so I can't write (x.name) , you know..

Comment: @Ilefjlassi, because of `select new {name = product.name, ..., id = product.Id}`, both `name` and `id` are from the product, not from the order. Shouldn't the quantity come from the orders table? Also if an order can have many products, a orders detail table should be involved. The order table would have the order date and shipment info, whereas the orders detail table would have the product id and the quantity. Either the database schema is wrong or your query is.

Comment: I'm sorry it was a typo, I modified the question. The quantity come from the order table

Answer (score 3):

You may run this simple query as native and receive the result.

```sql
select * from 
(
  select p.id, p.name, sum(o.quantity) qty 
  from "order" as o 
  inner join product as p on o.productid = p.id
  where o.date = current_date
  group by p.id -- and p.name if p.id is not primary key
) as t
order by qty desc
limit 5;
```